# How to find inverse order vector in R?

Tags: r

Say I have my data `x` and a random order vector:

```
rand_order <- sample(length(x))
```

now I can reshuffle my data with this random order and do something with them:

```
y <- x[rand_order]
```

now, how can I inverse-reshuffle `y`? I.e. how can i find `inverse_rand_order` so that `y[inverse_rand_order] == x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your ordering index, and then use `order` on it:

```
x <- 1:10
z <- sample(length(x))
y <- x[z]
#  [1]  4  1 10  6  9  5  2  8  3  7

y[order(z)]
#  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```